# Question Voting Tooltip Discussion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, voting

### Question Downvote Tooltip

Recently I downvoted a question that was just dumping code on reviewers without any effort to put readers in context or anything whatsoever. There's a tooltip on the downvote button that is very useful on most Stack Exchange Q&A sites:

> [image: downvote tooltip]
>
> <sub>**Downvote tooltip**</sub>

However on CR, we're a bit different and this tooltip isn't quite helpful. I think it would be nice if it were possible to change it for something else. But what?

> **1. If we could change the question downvote tooltip, what should it say?**

---

### Question Upvote Tooltip

So I looked at the upvote tooltip as well:

> [image]
>
> <sub>**Upvote tooltip**</sub>

Again, on CR a question doesn't need to show "research effort", the tooltip isn't quite helpful here either. I think it would be nice if it were possible to change it for something else. But what?

> **2. If we could change the question upvote tooltip, what should it say?**

---

#### Answer Voting Tooltips

Tooltips for answers simply say *"This answer is useful"* or *"This answer is not useful"*, which is simple, but effective and always true. In my opinion they're fine.

Answer (score 6):

How about the following? It's a straightforward, simple, one-sentence approach.

> ## Upvote
>
> This question provides enough details for review
>
> ## Downvote
>
> This question does not provide enough details for review

I used "details" instead of "context" to keep the terms simple. This makes it easy for our non-english users or those with not-so-deep vocabulary (like me at some point).

Answer (score 5):

**Downvote:**

> <s>*This question does not show any effort to put reviewers in context, it's not clear what the review is about, what's expected from answers or even whether the code actually works.*</s>

> *This question does not provide enough context to reviewers, or is otherwise unclear.*

**Upvote:**

> <s>*This question shows an effort to put reviewers in context, it's clear what the review is about, what's expected from answers and whether the code actually works.*</s>

> *This question is clear and provides enough context to reviewers.*

---

I guess that would be *one* reason to downvote/upvote.

Comment: This may be a little bit too.. long.

Comment: It could be <strike>shortened</strike> *refactored* into "This question does (not) provide enough information for reviewers"